# master controller with buttons needs to load pageviewcontroller. master buttons not accessible after first load

Tags: ios, navigation, xcode5, gestures

I am new to xcode and IOS (and this board. First post).

I am completely flummoxed by a design problem and unsure how to approach.

I have three buttons, each of which calls a new array of pages that need to navigate horizontally with swipe gestures and have their own buttons.

The three buttons in the parent work exactly like a tab bar except they have to be bigger and higher than a tab bar would be. The called page arrays mostly work like a pageviewcontroller except that the pages need to have a button/indicator below to allow non sequential navigation. The target HAS TO LOAD WITH A SEGUE.

The problem I'm encountering is that using a modal segue to load a pageviewcontroller and prepareForSegue to keep the master/parent view controller visible results in my buttons being inaccessible. I assume its because I cant click thought the child view controller.

Secondly, I don't know if its possible to customize the page indicator dots of a pageviewcontroller so they can look like a bar with graphics.

Here are my specific questions:

- Is it possible to load a view controller with a modal segue and still access my buttons? Can the child be resized?
- can i customize the buttons/indicators in a pageviewcontroller. Can you point me to some code?
- should navigation like this be done with some completely different approach? What about a view controller container?

  [Here's a diagram (cant post images directly yet)](https://flic.kr/p/nW1VNc)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my second question: It seems that pageViewController's indicators are not customizable in any way. This rules out pageViewController for what I need.

9 Views in 10 hours. Is this not the best forum for questions like this or is there something wrong with my post?